# Fatal error on Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu

I have installed Zend framework on Ubuntu 10.10.
I just created a project with zend tool.

However if I see http://localhost/zftest/public I get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 
'Configuration array must have a key for 'password' for login credentials' 
in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:284 Stack trace: 
#0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(183): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->_checkRequiredOptions(Array) 
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Db.php(265): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) 
#2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(142): Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', Array) 
#3 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(154): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->getDbAdapter() 
#4 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(680): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->init() 
#5 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(623): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db') 
#6 /usr/share/php/libzend-framewor in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 284
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Searching for that error message would have yielded the results you're after. First hit is http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/installation-configuration-3/zend_db_adapter_exception-2934.html

Comment: ... and just in case you're attempting to connect via a password-less MySQL user account, I don't think ZF supports such a thing, unless you want to try an empty password value

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework Db Adapter searches for an username and password field in your database configuration parameters if it can't find it you get that error.

You can connect to the database using no password, but you have to add the parameter password to your configuration, just leave it empty:

resources.db.adapter = MYSQLI
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password =

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html